# Use Enter button for submit, while working normally elsewhere

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that opens a GUI with a simple interface, which closes with Esc, and submits through the button. The script always runs in the background. I'm trying to find a way to make the Enter key work as a submit, but while still working normally everywhere else. I've tried using IfWinActive, but it doesn't work. Any ideas? thanks! (btw some of the code looks messy in this format, but the "unnecessary details" are there because this isn't the full script.)

```
Lwin & MButton::
Goto, Start
return


Start:
IfWinNotExist, New
{
    Gui,1:-border
    gui, font, s24, Product Sans  ; Set 10-point Product Sans.
    Gui, Add, Text,, Type here to search:                                      ;controls the UI
    Gui, Add, Edit, vTextInput
    Gui, Add, Button, -WantReturn gSubmit w80, Go
    Gui, Show, w400 h300, New
    IfWinExist, New
    Hotkey, Enter, Submit, On
    return
}
Else
Return

IfWinExist, New
Esc::Gui, Destroy
return

IfWinExist, New
Enter::
Goto, Submit
return



Submit:
Gui, Submit                          ;destroys the UI when submitted
GuiControlGet, TextInput
Gui, Destroy

Else
{
    link = https://www.google.com/search?q= %TextInput%                            ;search google 
    Run, %link%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code really looks like some real horror haha.
So much legacy AHK or stuff that doesn't work. But anyway, can't fix all that since that isn't the full script.

The answer to the actual question is to make your button the [default button](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#DefaultButton):

```
Gui, -Border
Gui, Font, s24, % "Product Sans"
Gui, Add, Text, , % "Type here to search:"
Gui, Add, Edit, vTextInput
Gui, Add, Button, +Default gSubmit w80, % "Go"
Gui, Show, w400 h300, % "New"
return

Submit:
    Gui, Submit
    Run, % "https://www.google.com/search?q=" TextInput
return
```

Sure, you could also define your own hotkey, like you tried to, but there's just no reason to when the above is so convenient.

Comment: thanks! Yeah, I figured it'd be a mess since I haven't updated my scripts for at least year, hahaha.